# OpenCV error: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'opencv_gapi.lib'

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, error-handling

I am trying to complie a simple code in visual studio code and opencv, on windows using Msys but I am getting this error.

I have try adding the libs and changing the includes but it doesn't work.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;

  PGMImage inImg (argv[1]);
  Mat image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR);
  namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  imshow("Display window", image);
  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

I am using cude for some other parts of the project but this is faling.

```
$ nvcc houghBase.cu pgm.cpp -o hough -I "C:\msys64\mingw64\include\opencv4" `pkg-config --libs opencv4`
houghBase.cu
pgm.cpp
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'opencv_gapi.lib'
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: "fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'opencv_gapi.lib'" - Seems simple enough - the file is not there, so you cannot open it. Fix that first.

Comment: @JesperJuhl but where should I get that file? The instalation for "opencv" was only pacman -Syu mingw-w64-x86_64-opencv

Comment: I am confused why you get a `msvc` linker error (and its looking for a msvc library)
 instead of a MinGW error and library but I don't use cuda.

Comment: Changing header files will not help you find a library. Using the `-L` option might, but I'm not familiar with this set up.